# automatically change localhost to my servername when typed on url

Tags: localhost, virtualhost

I have succeeded changing my htdocs directory and added a servername.but my problem for now is, how can i automatically changed the localhost to my servername when localhost is accessed.
Like when i typed in to the url localhost/onlineshopping/ it will automatically changed to sniper/onlineshopping/.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\jp"
    ServerName sniper
    ServerAlias sniper
    <Directory "C:\xampp\jp">
        Options Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you tried from your windows hosts file?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost sniper
::1   localhost sniper

Comment: is there anymore code to add?i really dont know how to solve that problem.ive tried to code a php for this but still i cant solved it

Comment: if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']!='sniper'){
     header("location:http://sniper");
    }

Comment: ive made that code but it's only working if your on index.php,how can i change that to all file

Comment: Note after you change your hosts file, make sure you flush your DNS cache.